# How to get jpql of named query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let say there is the below definition:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "name1", query = "SELECT n FROM SomeEntity n where n.name= :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "name2", query = "SELECT n FROM SomeEntity n where n.name <> :name")
})
public class SomeEntity ......
```

How to programmatically get a definition of the named query ?
For example the bellow code snippet should print a definition of `name1` query, I don't know how to get this definition in code:

```
String queryString = ????????.getSqlOfNamedQuery("name1");
// the below line should print: SELECT n FROM SomeEntity n where n.name= :name
System.out.println( queryString );
```

Comment: What "SQL"? The query is JPQL. If you want to see what SQL the JPA provider executes you look in their log, OR you look in their documentation for whether they have a vendor extension allowing visibility of the SQL before execution

Comment: @DN1 sorry - yes I want to get JPQL, not SQL

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unwrap` method and provide it with a vendor specific class. I saw this in an [old DZone article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-get-jpqlsql-string). I've tested the EclipseLink version and it works for me:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("....");
```

For EclipseLink:

```
String sqlString = query.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery().getSQLString();
```

For Hibernate:

```
String sqlString = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
```

You could also check your database logs (i.e. `/var/log/postgres/postgres.log`) but you might have other requirements that necessitate a programmatic approach.